# "out of wrong" usage

Tags: phrase-usage

Is it OK to use "out of wrong" in a paper for application of a method?

For example:

> the assumption that ... is true, hence the application of ... method is out of wrong.

Is there a better alternative?

Comment: *Out of wrong* definitely sounds incorrect.  But it's hard to tell you what is "better", because you haven't told us what you're trying to say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use of "out of"**

No, your sentence is not correct. You can use "out of" to indicate that you do not possess some object, for example:

> The grocery store was out of apples, so I bought some pears instead.
>
> I wanted to buy the latest video game, but I was out of cash.

Unfortunately, you can't use "out of" with an adjective. In order to use "out of", it needs to a thing that's lacking, not an attribute. For adjectives, you can either use "not + adjective" or simply use the adjective's opposite.

**Suggested Alternative**

In your case, the simplest thing to do would be to say:

> ... the method is **correct**.

The one exception would be if you're trying to emphasize that the method is not wrong, but the implication might be that it may not be right either:

> ... the method is **not wrong**, [but it's not right either].

Answer (score 0):

No, this is incorrect. Either

1. ...method is wrong/incorrect.
2. ...method is out of order.

Without more context either of these works but 1. is more common.

Comment: I mean the opposite. the method is correct.

Comment: @parisa - Then why not just say "the method is not wrong"?